# Scrapy not return results with xpath

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

i am trying make scrapping to get stats in this url

http://www.acb.com/redaccion.php?id=133495

I firstly try with player name:

import scrapy
import requests
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from ligafemanager.items import LigafemanagerItem

```
class Lf1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lf1'
    allowed_domains = ['acb.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.acb.com/redaccion.php?id=133495']
    def parse(self, response):
    self.logger.info('A response from %s just arrived!', response.url)
    i = LigafemanagerItem()
    i['acb_player_name'] = response.xpath('//td/div/codigo/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/font/text()').extract()
    self.logger.info('------------ACB NAME is: %s ------', 
    i['acb_player_name'])
    return i
```

never return results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thats a tricky one, because what you see is not the real truth. Consider the html from Firebug

[image: Firebug]

Now see the View source of the same page

[image: View Source]

All the ones highlighted in read are tags with error in firefox view source windows. Also notice one key thing `tbody` is missing. This is what happens with many sites, there is not tbody used in the HTML but browser does its autocorrection and add tbody to display the table correctly in browser.

When you are working with script the tbody is not there in the source and since scrapy won't do any auto correction, your XPATH with tbody won't find the element your are interested in. So simplest solution? Remove tbody from your xpath

```
In [3]: response.xpath('//td/div/codigo/table[1]/tr/td[2]/font/text()').extract()
Out[3]: ['Nombre']
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for your help, one question, if i write 

     //td/div/codigo/table/tr/td[2]/font/text()').extract()

Not return all names, only the first TR ¿Solution?

Comment: Well that should be "//td/div/codigo//table/tr/td[2]/font/text()" You need to use "//" for matching any child node. So instead of `/table` you use `//table`